# Not able to start/ initiate RODEO from the terminal, did anyone come across this?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ide

I am trying to use RODEO by YHAT, a data science IDE. I have installed it and have been trying to initiate it so that I could try and use it but it is not starting.

Environment : 
Operating system: Ubuntu 15.04  64  bit
I tried various browsers, chromium, chrome and firefox.

Here are two of the responses I got. [image: one response]

[image: another response]

Comment: Try actually pasting your terminal output for better readability

Comment: It is better if you post the actual text (cut it, paste on [so], and press Ctrl+K while selected), that way the text is better readable and can be searched. Show your not appreciation of help by accepting and voting, **not** by including chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).